# zsh completion for list of possible values of an environment variable

Tags: zsh-completion

Consider an environment variable that can take a list of arbitrary possible meaningful values. For an example of such an environment variable consider `AWS_PROFILE`. The list of possible values can be easily computed by some command, e. g. `aws configure list-profiles`. Is there any way I can write a custom completion such as whenever I type

```
% AWS_PROFILE=<TAB>
% AWS_PROFILE=partial-profile-nam<TAB>
```

or

```
% export AWS_PROFILE=<TAB>
% export AWS_PROFILE=partial-profile-nam<TAB>
```

I can get the completion function run and suggest the list of possible values.